# Yodlee REST API: How to resolve CobrandUserAccountLockedException?

Tags: yodlee

Currently, I am making the following **POST** call:

> **https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/authenticate/coblogin?cobrandLogin=sbCobFoo&cobrandPassword=Bar**

(Note that I inserted a fake login and password for the purpose of this post). I am getting the following response:

```
{"Error":[{"errorDetail":"The account for user sbCobFoo is locked"}]}
```

I wasn't able to find anything in the Yodlee documentation, other than that this error represents CobrandUserAccountLockedException. Has any one encountered this error and/or know how to resolve it (i.e. unlock my account)?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reach out to your Yodlee Customer Service representative to get your credentials unlocked. Yodlee does not provide any API to unlock user/cobrand account(s).